# 2D Ricochet Physics not working in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, physics, game-physics

I am trying to make a game where a ball will be ricocheting off several different colliders on screen. Based on what I researched I got some code that seemed to make sense at first but does not seem to work at all. I am testing it out just by having the ball fall down onto a 2D floor with a box collider attached to it. However once it collides with the floor it just stops there and doesn't bounce back up. I tried disabling "Queries Start in Colliders" in the project settings and offsetting the origin position of the RaycastHit2D so that it would not detect the collider its attached to but that still didn't work. I don't think the RaycastHit2D is working at all because it doesn't even display anything in the console. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public float speed;
    public float hitOffset;
    Vector3 vector = new Vector3(0, 5,0); //used to offset origin point of RaycastHit2D hit

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        this.transform.position = startPos;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);


        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + vector, - transform.up, speed * Time.deltaTime + hitOffset);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, -transform.up, Color.red);

        Ray2D ray = new Ray2D(transform.position, -transform.up);

        if (hit)
        {
            Debug.Log(speed * Time.deltaTime + hitOffset);
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
            Vector2 reflectDir = Vector2.Reflect(ray.direction,hit.normal);

            float rotation = Mathf.Atan2(reflectDir.y, reflectDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rotation);
        }

    }

}
```

Is my math bad? Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you went with this method instead of adding a Physics2D material to your ball and then setting friction to 0 and bounciness to 1?

Comment: I did not realize this was an option lol. I will definitely try this, but I would still like to know why my method doesn't work. Pretty new to unity and C# so I'd like to be educated on the subject.

Comment: So, would I need to download this asset from a third party, because when I set the rigidbody as kinematic and try to select a material the only option is none.

Comment: Nope, you've gotta make the material first. just right click in your assets folder->Create->Physics Material 2D and assign that to your rbody

Comment: I eventually figured that out after a few vids, but the only problem was that sometimes the ball would just slide across the surface of a wall collider if the angle of incident was small enough. I went back to  my original method and eventually got it to work by not using RaycastHit2D at all and instead used OnCollisionEnter2D and the normal of the contact point between the ball collider and the wall collider. I kept the regular Ray2D to use for the direction in the reflection function. Why are simple mechanics so hard lol.

Comment: @boblook, to prevent ball from sliding go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics 2D and set Velocity Threshold to minimum (0.0001).